# Python: Use variable as a lookup reference in CSV and return value

Tags: python, csv, lookup

Couldn't find an answer to this solution, so once I figured it out I thought I'd re-post my solution...

I was looking for a way of taking a user input (`sys.argv[1]`) and use this value to perform a lookup in a CSV file for another value in column x (e.g. 5). This would be part of a larger script and I would use the looked-up value as a test.

My example csv would be:

```
col0,col1,col2,col3,col4
a,foo,bar,blah,1
b,foo,bar,blah,2
c,foo,bar,blah,3
d,foo,bar,blah,4
e,foo,bar,blah,5
f,foo,bar,blah,6
g,foo,bar,blah,7
h,foo,bar,blah,8
i,foo,bar,blah,9
j,foo,bar,blah,10
k,foo,bar,blah,11
l,foo,bar,blah,12
m,foo,bar,blah,13
n,foo,bar,blah,14
o,foo,bar,blah,15
p,foo,bar,blah,16
q,foo,bar,blah,17
r,foo,bar,blah,18
s,foo,bar,blah,19
t,foo,bar,blah,20
u,foo,bar,blah,21
v,foo,bar,blah,22
w,foo,bar,blah,23
x,foo,bar,blah,24
y,foo,bar,blah,25
z,foo,bar,blah,26
```

Comment: @esaelPsnoroMoN: it looks to me like the OP actually posted his self-answer to the question before you asked him what was tried (10:47:38 vs 10:49:31).

Comment: that is correct... it's something I've been over thinking for a while, and it turns out to be really simple. So I thought i'd share, and if anyone has suggestions for improvement I'd welcome them and I'm sure others would too. :-)_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a quick look at your Javascript question, and if you're only ever mapping char->position in alphabet, what about the following?

```
def char_to_pos(char):
    from string import ascii_lowercase
    try:
        return ascii_lowercase.index(char) + 1
    except ValueError as e:
        pass # no match - do what's sensible here
```

And if you wanted to pre-generate a lookup table, then something like:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from itertools import count

lookup = dict(zip(ascii_lowercase, count(1)))
# or depending on taste
lookup = {letter: idx for idx, letter in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, start=1)}
```

Otherwise, since CSV files are generally relativey small you could just load the entire file to RAM to avoid repeated sequential lookups later (as long as the CSVs not so large it'll put your machine in a coma)

```
with open('test1.csv') as fin:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin)
    lookup = {row[0]: row for row in csvin}

to_find = 'x'
try:
    print '{} = {[4]}'.format(to_find, lookup[to_find])
except (KeyError, IndexError) as e:
    pass # KeyError = no lookup match, IndexError is that CSV file didn't have 5th column...
```

Comment: This is not the same project as the JavaScript one, this is different. I'll be matching a string (user input as a device model) in the CSV and outputting another string (which would be something like OS-type). I do like the info as I'm still learning (so I will upvote), however is your 3rd piece of code any more efficient than mine? - I thought I was loading it to memory.

Also what would constitute a large CSV?

Comment: @MHibbin Your code creates a CSV reader object and reads line by line until a match is found (it doesn't appear to handle cases where a match is *not* found); this is fine for a once-off lookup. If the file was large, and lookups are repeated, then storing in a more suitable data-structure is more appropriate. The 3rd example here loads into a `dict` stored in RAM (on most computer systems, a couple of hundred Mb is not unreasonable to have for an oft-used table) and enables you to use the functionality of a `dict` (quick lookup time) and easier handling of missing keys/default values.

Comment: @MHibbin You may also want to consider that instead of using a CSV file to store data, using a simple DB such as Sqlite3 which is part of the Python stdlib since 2.5. That'll enable you to keep it on-disk, but maintain indexes on lookup columns, and perform more complex queries (if required) in SQL rather than coding them in Python `select sum(col4) from your_table where col0 not in ('a','e','i','o','u') group by col4` etc...

Comment: I don't foresee the CSV getting to be that large. Also I have to use CSV as it interacts with another application that uses CSV files

Answer (score 1):

The way I did this was as follows:

```
import sys
import csv
#define user input as variable
input = sys.argv[1]
# read csv file into "fooReader"
fooReader = csv.reader(open('test1.csv', 'rb'), delimiter = ',', quotechar="\"")
# read each row in "fooReader"
for row in fooReader:
        # define first row column as "value" for testing
        value = row[0]
        # test if value (1st column) is the same as input (user input)
        if value == input:
                # ...if it is then print the 5th column in a certain way
                print value + " = " + row[4]
```

This can then be used to assign `row[4]` as a variable in another test that is required.